# Cisco OTV vs L2 VPN

Tags: cisco, l2vpn, cisco-nexus

Cisco introduce OTV as solution to give two physical separate Data centers  l2 connectivity over common L3 network , so why we need that if we have L2 VPN solution ? and what is the benefits of implementing OTV and excluse L2 VPN ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short answer:

1. OTV allows for more than just two sites.  It prevents bridging loops better than spanning tree.
2. OTV controls unknown MAC flooding, and only advertises MACs to other sites as necessary.
3. OTV limits "local" protocols like STP, VTP, etc to the local site.
4. OTV prevents broadcast storms, L2 loops, etc from affecting more than one location.  With a L2 VPN, all can be affected.
5. OTV runs over IP.  You can use it where you can't get a L2VPN.

[Here's more info](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-7000-series-switches/white_paper_c11-574984.html).

Comment: but do you thunk that is  sufficient reasons for using this technology ? still L2vpn( when available)  more simple and clear , and you can tune STP and other Protocol to deny it from moving between sites and also reduce loops risk

Comment: There is no one right answer.  Each network will have different factors that may change the answer.  Yes, you can tune STP to mitigate many (but not all) of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have L2 VPN already and it works for you. You will surely spend lots of time and money to implement OTV, to potentially get benefit from OVT you might not need.